# How to export the schema for hibernate > 4.3

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

There are many post on how to export programmatically a schema with hibernate (e.g. [1]).

But with Hibernate 4.3 the class `org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration` got removed and I could not find any replacement for it.
How can I programmatically generate the ddl script with a hibernate version >=4.3? 
Since I'm using spring for setting up the entity manger, I also don't have to use a persitence.xml anymore and I would like to keep it that way.

[1] http://techblog.bozho.net/?p=935

Comment: where you able to get a solution for this, if so can you please post. I am in a similar situation where I do not use persistence.xml.

Comment: no sorry, I gave up on this one - but you might be able to get this done based on the answer of @mabi

Answer (score 2):

To expand on @geoand's answer, I wrote a standalone `SchemaGenerator` groovy script that triggers the `SchemaExport` class:

```
class SchemaGenerator {
static final void main(String[] args) {
    def outputPath = args[0]
    def classesDir = args[1]

    Configuration cfg = new Configuration()
    cfg.setProperty('hibernate.dialect', 'org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect')
    cfg.setProperty('hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto', 'create')

    addClasses(cfg, new File(classesDir), 'my.entity.package.prefix')

    SchemaExport export = new SchemaExport(cfg)
    export.outputFile = new File(outputPath)
    export.delimiter = ';'
    export.format = true

    export.execute(true, false, false, true)
}
// addClasses uses cfg.addAnnotatedClass(Class) where it grabs the Class instance
// with Class.forName(name) with name derived from iterating the file structure
// of the classesDir
}
```

The trick is finding the class files: I run this script with my build system after compilation has finished and pass it the path to my generated class files.

However, where you get the class instances from is not important, the main part is the `cfg.addAnnotatedClass()` call to make Hibernate aware of them.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the class `org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport` is the class that deals with DDL in Hibernate. If you check the Spring logs, this is the class that is used to invoke DDL operations.

I don't know however how you could use this class on your own

Answer (score 1):

I used [org.reflections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections) to scan the classpath for classes that are annotated with @Entity and added them to the configuration.

Additionally I added 
  AuditConfiguration.getFor(cfg);
to generate the Audit tables.

After that I used the already mentioned SchemaExport to export the Schema.

```
    //set the package to scan
    Reflections reflections = new Reflections("my.packages.dao");

    //find all classes annotated with @Entity        
    Set<Class<?>> typesAnnotatedWith = reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(Entity.class);

    //create a minimal configuration
    Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
    cfg.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");
    cfg.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");

    for(Class<?> c : typesAnnotatedWith){
        cfg.addAnnotatedClass(c);
    }

    //build all the mappings, before calling the AuditConfiguration
    cfg.buildMappings();

    //configure Envers
    AuditConfiguration.getFor(cfg);

    //execute the export
    SchemaExport export = new SchemaExport(cfg);
    export.setOutputFile(fileName);
    export.setDelimiter(";");
    export.setFormat(true);

    export.execute(true, false, false, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

At [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23310617/how-to-use-schemaexporttool-with-jpa-and-hibernate-4-3) post I use a solution based on casting SessionFactory to Hibernate SessionFactoryImpl and using sessionfactory internal schema export object. It´s not the best solutions but works and is simple.

**EDIT**

URL FIXED.

Comment: @danielmelobrasil The link you posted assumes to have persistence.xml, but the author of the question here is not using persistence.xml