# Re-create H2 schema in Hibernate programatically

Tags: java, hibernate, h2, hbm2ddl

I'd like to use an in-memory db (H2) to preprocess, validate, etc some import-data before persisting it to the "real" production database. Prior to each import I'd like to recreate the H2 schema to have a clean database, as with hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto:"create". Is there any way to call hbm2ddl programatically or how else can I trigger the schema creation?

I'm using Spring Boot 1.3.3 with Hibernate 5.0.5.

Thank you for your help!

Cheers,
Maria

Answer (score 0):

in the meantime I've found the following solution and it worked for me:
https://github.com/valery-barysok/spring4-hibernate5-stackoverflow-34612019

The solution is explained in [Programmatic SchemaExport / SchemaUpdate with Hibernate 5 and Spring 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34612019/programmatic-schemaexport-schemaupdate-with-hibernate-5-and-spring-4)

Thanks, 
Maria