# org.hibernate.boot.model.TypeContributor: Provider not found

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, kotlin, serviceloader

I am trying to registrer *list-array* type provided by [hibernate-types](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.vladmihalcea/hibernate-types-52) library using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42695340/7196489) approach in spring boot app. Unfortunatelly, when I start the app from console it throws the following exception:

```
WARN  o.h.b.r.c.i.AggregatedServiceLoader - HHH000505: Ignoring ServiceConfigurationError caught while trying to instantiate service 'interface org.hibernate.boot.model.TypeContributor'.
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.hibernate.boot.model.TypeContributor: Provider org.example.CustomTypeContributor not found
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:588) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.nextProviderClass(ServiceLoader.java:1211) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNextService(ServiceLoader.java:1220) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1264) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$2.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1299) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderSpliterator.tryAdvance(ServiceLoader.java:1483) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$1Adapter.hasNext(Spliterators.java:681) ~[na:na]
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.AggregatedServiceLoader$ClassPathAndModulePathAggregatedServiceLoader.hasNextIgnoringServiceConfigurationError(AggregatedServiceLoader.java:241) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar!/:5.4.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.AggregatedServiceLoader$ClassPathAndModulePathAggregatedServiceLoader.loadAll(AggregatedServiceLoader.java:219) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar!/:5.4.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.AggregatedServiceLoader$ClassPathAndModulePathAggregatedServiceLoader.getAll(AggregatedServiceLoader.java:187) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar!/:5.4.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.loadJavaServices(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:251) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar!/:5.4.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:379) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar!/:5.4.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar!/:5.4.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1202) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar!/:5.4.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1233) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar!/:5.4.12.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391) ~[spring-orm-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:378) ~[spring-orm-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1108) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.example.Application.main(FamilyApplication.kt:10) ~[classes!/:1.1.44-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) ~[family-1.1.44-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.1.44-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) ~[family-1.1.44-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.1.44-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51) ~[family-1.1.44-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.1.44-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52) ~[family-1.1.44-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.1.44-SNAPSHOT]
```

Here how it is configured:

```kotlin
package org.example

import com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.array.ListArrayType
import org.hibernate.boot.model.TypeContributions
import org.hibernate.boot.model.TypeContributor
import org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry
import java.sql.Types

class CustomPgDialect : PostgreSQL95Dialect() {
    init {
        registerHibernateType(Types.ARRAY, "list-array")
    }
}

class CustomTypeContributor : TypeContributor {
    override fun contribute(typeContributions: TypeContributions, serviceRegistry: ServiceRegistry) {
        typeContributions.contributeType(ListArrayType.INSTANCE)
    }
}
```

Classname is localted at `src\main\resources\META-INF\services\org.hibernate.boot.model.TypeContributor` with content:

```
org.example.CustomTypeContributor
```

I have the following package configuration:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>unpack</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>unpack</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <artifactItems>
                    <artifactItem>
                        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                        <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                        <version>${project.version}</version>
                        <type>jar</type>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/application
                        </outputDirectory>
                    </artifactItem>
                </artifactItems>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The application is started by: `java -cp ./application/ org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher`

What is the problem?

Thanks

Comment: As I see it, the CustomDialect is redundant or even the cause of you bug.

Comment: 5 upvotes, no answers, 3 years old. gulp.