# How to configure Hibernate (via Spring Boot) to use `NumericBooleanType` for all boolean columns

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

How can I configure Hibernate to use its built-in type [NumericBooleanType](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/javadocs/org/hibernate/type/NumericBooleanType.html) for every boolean column without using any annotation (`@Type`) on each column?

Edit: A little more background - the goal is to support Oracle as well as Postgres with one codebase and since Oracle has no `boolean` type I want to make Postgres store boolean values like Oracle with `0/1`

Comment: Well can't you use that type instead of bool in your java code? (FYI I'm a beginner)

Comment: I know I could use `@Type` but I want to override the default so I don't have to repeat myself.

Answer (score 6):

You don't have to do anything if your database column has a numeric datatype and the entity has a boolean attribute.

If this does not work use the `@Type` annotation:

```
@Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.NumericBooleanType")
private boolean enabled;
```

Alternatively you could write a JPA Converter with auto apply:

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class FileConverter implements AttributeConverter<Boolean, Short> {

  @Override
  public Short convertToDatabaseColumn(Boolean value) {
      return value ? 1 : 0;
  }

  @Override
  public Boolean convertToEntityAttribute(Short dbData) {
      return dbData == 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: That does not work at least for Postgres. When saving an entity with a boolean field via Spring Data repository I get: `ERROR: column "my_boolean_column" is of type numeric but expression is of type boolean`

Comment: I explicitly do not want to use `@Type` because it can always be forgotten. Thank your for your response anyway I will clarify my question a little more.

Comment: The problem is that PostgreSQL has a boolean data type. So there will never happen an implicit conversion like for Oracle: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/4C9D661B.7010301%40postnewspapers.com.au

Comment: I don't understand - I mean it works when I use `@Type` so why shouldn't I be able to configure Hibernate to do the same thing without this annotation?

Comment: I've added an alternative but didn't test it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229057/discussion-between-hans-wurst-and-simon-martinelli).

Answer (score 1):

So with the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42695340) I was able to achieve what I want but it has the drawback that now I cannot explicitly configure Hibernate to fall back to its previous default mapping in case I would want to do that for some boolean fields. Hoping for more input from all of you :)

```
public class NumericBooleanTypeAsDefaultBooleanTypeRegistration implements SessionFactoryBuilderFactory {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(NumericBooleanTypeAsDefaultBooleanTypeRegistration.class);

    @Override
    public SessionFactoryBuilder getSessionFactoryBuilder(final MetadataImplementor metadata,
            final SessionFactoryBuilderImplementor defaultBuilder) {
        logger.info("Overriding BooleanType with NumericBooleanType as default Boolean type");
        metadata.getTypeConfiguration().getBasicTypeRegistry().register(new NumericBooleanType(),
                new String[] {"boolean"});
        return defaultBuilder;
    }
}
```

and as explained in the referenced answer I have to tell Hibernate about this class via the ServiceLoader mechanism:

- Create the file `src/main/resources/META-INF/org.hibernate.boot.spi.SessionFactoryBuilderFactory` with the content `mypackage.NumericBooleanTypeAsDefaultBooleanTypeRegistration`

Comment: Well, I learned something, thanks for updating the question!